# Clock input ignored while waveform simulation in VHDL?

Tags: counter, vhdl

I'm new to Hardware Description Language Theory and VHDL. I need to design a 2421 up counter in VHDL. I built a synchronous binary up counter using T flip flop and modified it to generate the last 2 desired counts of 8 and 9 by activating the preset and clear conditionally. When I try waveform simulation, the clock input gets ignored. Can't figure out what the problem is. Here is the code:

```
library ieee;  
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  
entity count2421 is    
port(clock:in std_logic;qq:buffer std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));  
end count2421;  
architecture arch of count2421 is  
component t_ff is  
port(clock,clear,preset,t:in std_logic;q:buffer std_logic);  
end component;  
signal p1,p2,p,t,u,a,b:std_logic;  
begin  
    t<='1';  
    u<='0';  
    qq(0)<='0';  
    qq(1)<='0';  
    qq(2)<='0';  
    qq(3)<='0';  
    process(clock) begin  
        if(clock'event and clock='0') then  
            p1<=(not qq(3)) and qq(2) and qq(1) and qq(0);  
            p2<=qq(3) and qq(2) and qq(1) and (not qq(0));  
            p<=p1 or p2;  
            a<=qq(3) and qq(2);  
            b<=a and qq(1);  
        end if;  
    end process;  
    stage0:t_ff port map(clock,u,p,t,qq(0));  
    stage1:t_ff port map(clock,u,p,qq(0),qq(1));  
    stage2:t_ff port map(clock,u,p,a,qq(2));  
    stage3:t_ff port map(clock,p1,p2,b,qq(3));  
end arch;
```

Here is the T flip flop code:

```
library ieee;  
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  
  entity t_ff is  
    port(clock,clear,preset,t:in std_logic;q:buffer std_logic);  
  end t_ff;  
  architecture arch of t_ff is  
signal temp:std_logic;  
begin  
    temp<=q;  
    process(clock)  
    begin  
        if(clock'event and clock='0') then  
            if(clear='1') then   
                q<='0';  
            elsif(preset='1') then  
                q<='1';  
            elsif(t='1') then  
                q<=not q;  
            end if;  
        end if;  
    end process;  
end arch;
```

Comment: how are you generating your clock input?

Answer (score 0):

Buffer port qq has two drivers.
Fix that first before worrying about anything else.